# How can the Citizens provide a Better Environment for Politicians when Facing the News Media?

Tags: public-opinion, political-system, polling

I recently watched a rather old video from Jay Foreman that seems even relevant today:

[Why don't politicians answer questions?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8QOE-IWo3I)

As he explains the reasons behind it, I wonder are we placing too much of a burden on politicians in these unsavorily polarizing times. I do agree that politicians need to be questioned by the media, but when I watch the interviews, they only deflect or provide non answers to the questions. At the same time, conducting interviews with easy/softball questions is not beneficial as they lead to lack of accountability. So, going forward how can we reconcile this rather fragile equilibrium and actually get some factual answers by them?

Have any studies by political experts/academics looked at reasons for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your Youtube personality already explains, the problem isn't so much that the media is mean, it's the inherent problem of job insecurity.

If you want people to be frank and to admit failures and mistakes you have to provide an environment that is tolerant of that. While if you have a highly competitive environment where failure is seen as a weakness and where every misstep can have devastating results and where you personally are seen as having all the responsibility. You're simply way more likely to deflect, deny, obfuscate and say engage in fluff and meaningless rhetoric.

The problem is, that's not something that the people or the media can change. It's part of the job itself and the politicians are themselves to blame for that.

They actively campaign for a position of power and privilege because they claimed that they are the best for the job. So they raise the bar for themselves and their competitors to sometimes super human levels. Like if you look at presidents and whatnot, it's often close to a cult of personality, when in reality these are average people that only have any sort of power and privilege because they are supposed to represent a much bigger group. So it's not actually them being powerful, it's them standing in front of a very large and thus very powerful group that possesses that actual power.

And the more these people claim to have or want to have actual power to decide things personally or take personal credit for the collective work of millions of people, the more they personally will be scrutinized. And for good reason.

So the only real way to get around that problem is to abolish the idea of dedicated leaders, disperse power over larger groups, make the process more transparent and make it more understandable what the problems are that you are facing and how you actually try to solve them and make them define metrics as to whether that is working or not.

However in that case politicians would be taken down from their pedestal and as difficult and shortlived as the job might be, probably few want to pass on the privilege and praise that comes with "leadership" and "assumed responsibility" which make them appear larger than life.

Comment: I'm not really convinced. There are lots of times when we can choose someone to be in charge and recognize they are the best to be in charge while also realizing they are not omniscient beings. But they certainly do try to cultivate that image.

Comment: @user253751 It isn't that common for politicians to attack one another for failing especially when they have admitted that they where wrong on something.

Comment: @JoeW and whose fault is it this reflects badly on the one receiving the attack, rather than making the one doing the attacking seem like a hypocrite because everyone knows he wouldn't do any better?

Comment: @user253751 Did I try to place blame? Just saying that when people face consequences for admitting they are wrong or making a stance on an opinion it isn't hard to see why they try to avoid that.

Comment: @JoeW the answer above these comments involves blame, which is also related to my comment.

Comment: @user253751 And the list of people to blame for that is pretty much everyone which is why I don't assign blame. First you got the people attacking others for it, then you got the people spreading those attacks, you also have the people spreading those attacks, and finally you have the people taking action based on those attacks.  There is no shortage of people who are at fault for the systems flaws.

Comment: @user253751 It doesn't have to be a superhuman image, but politicians are certainly required to cultivate an image of themselves as competent and the less they get concrete on issues the more people are able to project their ideas on them, which ironically might even shield them from failures if people assume they failed in good faith and no one could have done it better. And sure that's not just on the politician, but on the voters, the media, the campaign team, the competitors and so on, the point is that it's in inherent to the job even if you reduce the rest.